# android - FATAL EXCEPTION: main unable to start Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fatal-error

My Log cat

```
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer/com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.showBudgetActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc80
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc80
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3844)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.showBudgetActivity.onCreate(showBudgetActivity.java:50)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-07 16:50:54.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1697):     ... 11 more
```

OK now the Code for the Activity which is not opening

```
public class showBudgetActivity extends Activity {

TextView sb1, sb2, sb3, sb4, sb5, sb_r;

Button showBudget_backButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showbudget_activity);

    sb_r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_showBudget_rBudget);

    sb1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_SB_H2);
    sb2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_SB_T2);
    sb3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_SB_F2);
    sb4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_SB_S2);
    sb5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_SB_O2);

    showBudget_backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_showBudget);


    tourDB gettingInfo = new tourDB(this);

    gettingInfo.open();

    long getlastID = gettingInfo.getMaxID();

    int prev_remainbudget = gettingInfo.getPrevRemainBudget(getlastID);

    int prev_rent = gettingInfo.getRentPrev(getlastID);
    int prev_transport = gettingInfo.getTransportPrev(getlastID);
    int prev_food = gettingInfo.getFoodPrev(getlastID);
    int prev_shopping = gettingInfo.getShoppingPrev(getlastID);
    int prev_other = gettingInfo.getOtherPrev(getlastID);

    gettingInfo.close();

    sb_r.setText(prev_remainbudget);

    sb1.setText(String.valueOf(prev_rent));
    sb2.setText(String.valueOf(prev_transport));
    sb3.setText(String.valueOf(prev_food));
    sb4.setText(String.valueOf(prev_shopping));
    sb5.setText(String.valueOf(prev_other));

    showBudget_backButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent openonGoingActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.ONGOINGACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openonGoingActivity);
            }
         });


    //fetchdatafromDataBase();
}

/*private void fetchdatafromDataBase() {

}*/
}
```

And Now This is the class where I'm calling the Activity

```
public class onGoingActivity extends ListActivity{

    static final String onGoingList[] = {"Enter Expenses","Remaining Budget","Click Photos","Close Tour Profile","Back"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new onGoingArrayAdapter(this, onGoingList));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String positionItem = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);


        if (positionItem.contentEquals("Enter Expenses")) {

            //mainMenuActivityItem = "createNewActivity_1";

            Intent openActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.EXPENSELISTACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openActivity);

        }else if (positionItem.contentEquals("Remaining Budget")) {

            //mainMenuActivityItem = "onGoingActivity";

            Intent openActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.SHOWBUDGETACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openActivity);

        }else if (positionItem.contentEquals("Click Photos")) {

            //mainMenuActivityItem = "tourListActivity";

            Intent openActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.PHOTOUPACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openActivity);

        }else if (positionItem.contentEquals("Famous Tourist Attractions")) {

            //mainMenuActivityItem = "famousTourActivity";

            Intent openActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.CLOSEPROFILEACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openActivity);

        }else if (positionItem.contentEquals("Back")) {

            //mainMenuActivityItem = "alarmSetActivity";

            Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.MAINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
        }

        /*

        if (selectExpense == "back"){
            Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer.MAINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
        }
        else {

        try{
            Class onGoingClass = Class.forName("com.blackcat.blackcattourorganizer." + selectExpense);
            Intent selectExpenseIntent = new Intent(onGoingActivity.this, onGoingClass);
            startActivity(selectExpenseIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

The manifest is very much ok.

Comment: Your error seems to come from a not found resource. May you share the code of your xml file ?

Comment: Xml File is too long...

Comment: @mhtamun Did you try my proposed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `String.valueOf()` for your `sb_r` `TextView`

Simply do:

```
sb_r.setText(String.valueOf(prev_remainbudget));
```

The `setText()` method of TextView attempts to find a resource id matching that number, if you give it an arbitrary int value, it won't find the resource, hence the `Exception`,

Comment: Very Much Thank you Sir. Yes I did try your proposed solution, and it worked. @A-C

Comment: @mhtamun Since my answer resolved your issue, you should be a good StackOverflow user and accept it by [clicking the hollowed out checkmark so it turns green](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202881). You get some rep and you indicate that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referencing a resource that does not exist, check all the R.x usage in your code exists in your resources

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc80
```